# How to open a text file in button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, fileopendialog

At this point I am note sure what I am doing wrong. I wrote these lines of code

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    try 
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.ShowDialog();
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            txtpath.Text = op.FileName;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

But this isn't working due to an error which states

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'OK'

It should be read out in a listbox.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be like this. `ShowDialog()` will block until the dialog is closed.

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
if (op.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault()) 
{ 
    txtpath.Text = op.FileName; 
}
```

Please format your questions correctly and tell us what errors you get (like compiler errors, exceptions, strange behaviour ...).

Comment: As nvoigt states in his answer: In WPF the method does _not_ return a DialogResult. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms614336(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`ShowDialog` returns a `bool?` in WPF. So:

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

var result = op.ShowDialog();

if (result.GetValueOrDefault());
{
    txtpath.Text = op.FileName;
}
```

Comment: [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms614336(v=vs.110).aspx): _"In the current implementation, the derived classes (OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog) will only return true or false."_ - So `if(op.ShowDialog())` should be enough, right?

Comment: @Fildor It still means that the type is `bool?` and you need to get the value. The compiler does not know that the nullable bool will in fact always be non-null.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Always forgetting that it doesn't work in that direction.